# std::map key not found even though the entries are identical

Tags: c++, templates, stdstring, stdmap

I'm learning C++ and I've been writing a wrapper for std::map and std::string, and I've stumbled upon a problem. Whenever I add something to the map using a string as key, once I try to access that item using the exact same key it says the key is out of bounds of the map. Here's my code (irrelevant parts left out):

`ADictionary.h`

```
#ifndef ADICTIONARY_H
#define ADICTIONARY_H

#include <map>

...

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class ADictionary {
public:
    ...

    VALUE operator [](KEY key) const {
        return value.at(key);
    }

    void add(KEY key, VALUE value) {
        this->value.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
    }

    ...

private:
    std::map<KEY, VALUE> value;
};

#endif
```

`AString.cpp`

```
#include "AString.h"

AString::AString() {
    value = "";
}

AString::AString(const char character) {
    value = character;
}

AString::AString(const char * characters) {
    value = characters;
}

AString::AString(std::string text) {
    value = text;
}

...

AString::operator const char *() const {
    return value.c_str();
}

AString::operator const std::string() const {
    return value;
}

...

ABoolean AString::operator<(AString & text) const {
    return getLength() < text.getLength();
}

ABoolean AString::operator>(AString & text) const {
    return text < *this;
}

ABoolean AString::operator==(AString & text) const {
    return value == text.value;
}

ABoolean AString::operator!=(AString & text) const {
    return !(text == *this);
}

AString & AString::operator=(AString & text) {
    value = text.value;

    return *this;
}

...
```

`The code which uses the above`

```
ADictionary<AString, AString> test;
AString a = "a";
AString b = "b";
test.add(a, b);
std::cout << test[a]; // Error occurs here, according to the program "a" is not a key in the map
```

I hope someone can explain to me what's going wrong. I've tried creating a dictionary with the default std::string as types and it worked correctly:

```
ADictionary<std::string, std::string> test;
std::string a = "a";
std::string b = "b";
test.add(a, b);
std::cout << test[a]; // No error this time
```

As I've said, I'm pretty new to C++ so there may be other errors. If so, feel free to point them out.

Thanks!

EDIT:

`AString.h`

```
#ifndef ASTRING_H
#define ASTRING_H

#include <string>

#include "ABoolean.h"
#include "AInteger.h"
#include "AList.h"

class ABoolean;
class AInteger;
template<typename VALUE>
class AList;

class AString {
public:
    AString();
    AString(const char);
    AString(const char *);
    AString(std::string);
    ~AString();

    operator const char *() const;
    operator const std::string() const;
    operator const AInteger() const;

    ABoolean operator<(AString &) const;
    ABoolean operator>(AString &) const;
    ABoolean operator==(AString &) const;
    ABoolean operator!=(AString &) const;
    AString & operator=(AString &);
    AString & operator+(AString &);
    AString & operator+=(AString &);

    void clear();
    ABoolean contains(AString) const;
    AInteger getIndex(AString) const;
    AInteger getLength() const;
    AList<AString> getSplit(AString) const;
    AString getSubstring(AInteger, AInteger) const;
    void removeRange(AInteger, AInteger);
    void removeSubstring(AString);
    void toLowercase();
    void toUppercase();

private:
    std::string value;
};

AString & operator+(const char, AString &);
AString & operator+(const char *, AString &);

#endif
```

Comment: You haven't included enough code to reproduce the problem. What is the definition of `AString`?

Comment: @NeilKirk The definition is included. Did you mean the declaration?

Comment: The whole thing. Otherwise how can I tell what type `value` is etc?

Comment: @NeilKirk Ah, I understand. I've edited the question and included the header.

Comment: change `operator<(AString &)` into `operator<(const AString &)`

Comment: std::map uses `operator<`, by default, to compare keys. Your `AString` uses the length to do its comparation, while the `std::string` compares the length AND also does a lexicographical comparison. Your comparison checks if length is smaller than the same string which is false.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Wow, that actually worked! It does make me wonder, when exactly is it required to make parameters constant?

Comment: @Qub1 without `const` it probably triggers conversion to `const char*` for making comparison

Comment: @Qub1 *"when exactly is it required to make parameters constant?"* always when you know you won't need to modify the argument

Comment: If it now works, it is because `AString::operator<` is not actually being called OR you haven't tried it with two keys are different value but equal length yet. The trouble with the conversion operators is it makes it difficult to predict which type will actually be used in a given situation.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes I've read somewhere it's best to always avoid using conversion operators, although I haven't found another way to easily convert the object without using them.

Comment: Use a function such as `ToString` or `AsString`

Comment: @NeilKirk Oh, yeah that's a great idea. Now I understand why higher languages use such functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string operators appear to be incorrect.

std::map uses the less than operator by default. While you provide one for AString, the only thing it does is check the length of the string. What if the two strings are of equal length?

The correct thing to do is to lexicographically compare the characters in the string. While there is a standard library function to do this, you can use operator < of the std::string values in your class:

```
friend bool operator<(AString const& a, AString const& b)
{
    return a.value < b.value;
}
```

EDIT: You may also wish to remove your conversion operators, or at least make them explicit, which prevents surprising and unwanted implicit conversions. Constructors taking one parameter (other than copy or move constructors) should also be declared explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works as expected. If I remove the conversion operators, what would be the recommended way to use my AString object as for example an std::string? Or is making them explicit the only way to go?

Comment: You can create an AString just by calling the appropriate constructor with a standard string, and convert back to a std::string by calling an explicit conversion operator, or a specially implemented member function (as Neil Kirk suggests above).